# Fazer um "distinct" em uma query com muitos campos no select

Tags: sql, sql-server

Nessa query, posso fazer uma espécie de distinct? Um Group By fica muito lento e são muitos campos. Distinct puro não resolve, pois são vários campos. Como seria isso?

```
DECLARE
@CodTerceiro int = 113773,  
@DataVencimentoIni datetime = null,   
@DataVencimentoFim datetime = null,   
@Pago  tinyint = 3    

SELECT pw.IdPedidoWeb,
        pw.IdPedido,
        Convert(DateTime,receber.E1_EMISSAO,103) as DataEmissao ,  
        Convert(DateTime,receber.E1_VENCTO, 103) as DataVencimento,     
        pedido.C5_XIDNF AS IdNotaFiscal,    
        pedido.C5_NOTA AS NroNotaFiscal, 
        receber.E1_VALOR AS VlrTotalNotaFiscal,

        CASE WHEN receber.E1_SALDO > 0
        THEN 'Em Aberto'
        ELSE 'Pago'
        END 'Status',

        pw.CodProduto,    
        pw.QtdItem,    
        pw.QtdItem * pw.VlrVenda 'VlrProduto'    
    FROM [dbo].[PedidoWeb] pw    
        WITH (NOLOCK, INDEX (Ind_PedidoWeb_2)) 

        INNER JOIN Totvs12.dbo.SC5010 pedido
        --WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON pedido.C5_XPEDSND = pw.IdPedido

        INNER JOIN Totvs12.dbo.SE1010 receber 
        --WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON receber.E1_FILIAL + receber.E1_NUM + receber.E1_PREFIXO = pedido.C5_FILIAL + pedido.C5_NOTA + pedido.C5_SERIE    

        WHERE pw.CodTerceiro = @CodTerceiro   
        AND Convert(DateTime,receber.E1_VENCTO, 103) >= coalesce (@DataVencimentoIni, Convert(DateTime,receber.E1_VENCTO, 103))    
        AND Convert(DateTime,receber.E1_VENCTO, 103) <= coalesce (@DataVencimentoFim, Convert(DateTime,receber.E1_VENCTO, 103))    

        AND 
        (   @Pago = 3    
            OR @Pago = CASE WHEN receber.E1_SALDO > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END)

        AND pedido.D_E_L_E_T_ = ''

        AND pw.IdPedidoWEb between '9000000' and '20000000'
```

Na query abaixo eu retorno apenas 75 registros e na query acima 213

```
select distinct idpedido from PedidoWeb where codterceiro = 113773 AND IdPedidoWEb between '9000000' and '20000000' 
and IdPedido  in (select distinct c5_xpedsnd from Totvs12.dbo.SC5010 where C5_Cliente = '113773')
```

A query de cima deveria ter o mesmo resultado, exceto alguma coisa que desconheço.

Comment: Poderia confirmar se o formato das colunas E1_EMISSAO e E1_VENCTO é `aaaammdd` e se ambas estão declaradas como char(8)?

Answer (score 2):

**(1)**
Antes de entrar na questão de 75 x 213 linhas retornadas, sugiro que analise as cláusulas FROM/ON e WHERE sob o ponto de vista de *[sargability](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/10/04/construindo-codigos-t-sql-eficientes-sargability/)*. Por exemplo, na cláusula FROM do seu código existe a seguinte construção:

```
INNER JOIN Totvs12.dbo.SE1010 receber 
--WITH (NOLOCK)
ON receber.E1_FILIAL + receber.E1_NUM + receber.E1_PREFIXO = pedido.C5_FILIAL + pedido.C5_NOTA + pedido.C5_SERIE
```

Essa concatenação de colunas nada mais é do que uma expressão, o que torna o predicado *non sargable*. Se as colunas receber.E1_FILIAL, receber.E1_NUM, e receber.E1_PREFIXO corresponderem às colunas pedido.C5_FILIAL, pedido.C5_NOTA e pedido.C5_SERIE, eis sugestão de alteração:

```
INNER JOIN Totvs12.dbo.SE1010 receber 
ON receber.E1_FILIAL = pedido.C5_FILIAL
   and receber.E1_NUM = pedido.C5_NOTA
   and receber.E1_PREFIXO =  pedido.C5_SERIE
```

---

**(2)**
Na cláusula WHERE também há predicados que necessitam de revisão. O trecho de código

```
   ...
   AND Convert(DateTime,receber.E1_VENCTO, 103) >= coalesce (@DataVencimentoIni, Convert(DateTime,receber.E1_VENCTO, 103))    
   AND Convert(DateTime,receber.E1_VENCTO, 103) <= coalesce (@DataVencimentoFim, Convert(DateTime,receber.E1_VENCTO, 103))    
   ...
```

necessita ser reescrito, pois `Convert(DateTime,receber.E1_VENCTO, 103)` torna o predicado *non sargable*.

Pelo que observei em outros tópicos, a coluna E1_VENCTO está declarada como char(8) e no formato aaaammdd. Se for isto, sugiro que realize a conversão de tipos no parâmetro, convertendo-o de datetime para char(8). Isto garante *sargability* ao predicado.

```
   ...
   AND receber.E1_VENCTO >= coalesce (convert( char(8), @DataVencimentoIni, 112), receber.E1_VENCTO)    
   AND receber.E1_VENCTO <= coalesce (convert( char(8), @DataVencimentoFim, 112), receber.E1_VENCTO)    
   ...
```

Avalie também a seguinte alternativa:

```
   ...
   AND (@DataVencimentoIni is null OR receber.E1_VENCTO >= convert( char(8), @DataVencimentoIni, 112))   
   AND (@DataVencimentoFim is null OR receber.E1_VENCTO <= convert( char(8), @DataVencimentoFim, 112))    
   ...
```

Sobre a questão de sargability, sugiro a leitura do artigo “[Construindo códigos T-SQL eficientes: Sargability](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/10/04/construindo-codigos-t-sql-eficientes-sargability/)”.

---

**(3)**
A respeito da diferença de retorno de linhas, 75 x 213, provavelmente se deve à conversão de data errada neste trecho de código:

```
Convert(DateTime,receber.E1_VENCTO, 103)
```

Considerando-se que a coluna E1_VENCTO declarada como char(8) e no formato aaaammdd, o correto é

```
Convert(DateTime,receber.E1_VENCTO, 112)
```

Mas é necessário também rever a questao de cardinalidade, citada por Mariana.