# Performance do sql server com joins concatenados

Tags: sql, sql-server

Fazer um **INNER JOIN** com as chaves concatenadas, da forma abaixo, quebra e/ou prejudica a performance do banco?

```
    INNER JOIN Totvs12.dbo.SE1010 receber 
    ON receber.E1_FILIAL + receber.E1_NUM + receber.E1_PREFIXO = pedido.C5_FILIAL + pedido.C5_NOTA + pedido.C5_SERIE 


   INNER JOIN Totvs12.dbo.SF2010 nota 
   ON pedido.C5_FILIAL + pedido.C5_NOTA  = nota.F2_FILIAL + nota.F2_DOC
```

Comment: Pra que fazer uma gambiarra dessa?

Comment: @pnet Você leu as observações sobre predicado _sargable_ postadas em  https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/376349/ *?*  A resposta está lá...

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Fazer um "distinct" em uma query com muitos campos no select](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/376349/fazer-um-distinct-em-uma-query-com-muitos-campos-no-select)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No trecho de código

```
INNER JOIN Totvs12.dbo.SE1010 receber 
ON receber.E1_FILIAL + receber.E1_NUM + receber.E1_PREFIXO = pedido.C5_FILIAL + pedido.C5_NOTA + pedido.C5_SERIE
```

essa concatenação de colunas nada mais é do que uma expressão, o que torna o predicado *non sargable*. Se as colunas `receber.E1_FILIAL`, `receber.E1_NUM` e `receber.E1_PREFIXO` corresponderem às colunas `pedido.C5_FILIAL`, `pedido.C5_NOTA` e `pedido.C5_SERIE`, eis sugestão de alteração:

```
INNER JOIN Totvs12.dbo.SE1010 receber 
ON receber.E1_FILIAL = pedido.C5_FILIAL
   and receber.E1_NUM = pedido.C5_NOTA
   and receber.E1_PREFIXO =  pedido.C5_SERIE
```

---

Sugiro a leitura do artigo “[Construindo códigos T-SQL eficientes: Sargability](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2018/10/04/construindo-codigos-t-sql-eficientes-sargability/)”.

Comment: Belo artigo, pena que não pude ainda lê-lo com o zelo que merece. Também gostei das marcas estilísticas do autor do texto linkado ;-)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Grato pelos comentários. O artigo possui também versão em arquivo, no formato PDF; é possível imprimi-la e depois ler o texto com calma. E, no mais, precisamos divulgar o conceito _sargability_, pois ele é o ponto de partida para otimização de consultas SQL.